# run an emulator without android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm using flutter on visual studio code and my android studio emulator doesn't work.
Is there a way I can run an emulator on visual studio code without android studio's help?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you run "flutter doctor" in your VS Code Terminal to determine any issues with your Android Studio and/or emulator. Then update your question with any errors that occur or simply write out the error you are getting from Android Studio when trying to start your emulator.

However, you won't have to use an emulator that is on Android Studio if you simply turn on Developer Mode/Options on your personal Android Device, then turn on "USB Debugging", this will allow you to run a version on your app on your phone as long as you have your phone connected to your computer through a USB cable.